# Avoid drop-down in some items on Codrops horizontal drop-down menu script

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

The Codrops script:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/05/horizontal-drop-down-menu/

How to make some choosen item from the menu a standard behavior link?

Eg Menu: Home | Categories | Contact | Authors

I want to make only Categories and Authors 'drop-downable'.

I tryed to insert a class .drop-down on `<li>` itens I want to make 'dropdownable'.

```
<nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="cbp-dropdown"> //added class here
            <a href="#">Categories</a>
            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
```

And replaced all `.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );` on jquery script with

```
.removeClass().addClass('cbp-dropdown')
```

It almost worked well. The close function doesn't work good when alterning 'tabs'.

How is the proper way to do this?

Original DEMO: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalDropDownMenu/

JSfiddle Original: http://jsfiddle.net/xC47v/1/

JSfiddle My Mod: http://jsfiddle.net/xC47v/2/ (clicking between main links doesn't close submenus.)

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle showing your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with trial and error

Just added the class on `<a>` tag instead of `<li>` tag.

Like: `<a href="#"  class="dropdown">Freeware</a>`

and on jquery script, modified the line to `$menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a.dropdown' ),`

It is working well.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xC47v/3/